# Create new component in Angular 6

Tags: angular

When i'm trying to create new component it shown this error and i couldn't create new component?

My global angular version is 6.1.5 and working projects angular version is also same.

After i enter this command ng generate component attend-events shown here error.

Schematic input does not validate against the Schema:

```
{"path":"/src/app/mp/settings","styleext":"scss","inlineStyle":false,"inlineTemplate":false,"changeDetection":"D
efault","spec":true,"flat":false,"skipImport":false,"export":false,"entryComponent":false,"lintFix":false}
```

Errors:

Data path "" should have required property 'name'.

Comment: You need to type that command once you are inside your app folder only

Comment: project_folder/src/app > ng g c attend-events

Comment: `ng g c attend-events --module=app` will also do

Comment: Let us know if it worked

Comment: Mr: Thanveer Shah. No it didn't work. i coudn't create component inside project_folder/src/app. shown same error i have mentioned above.

Comment: Mr:Joel Joseph it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find solution for above problem. you can create component like this.

> *ng g c --name* *`component-name`* or ng generate component --name 
>   *`component-name`*

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following command: `ng generate component <component-name>`